# Use Regular Expression to extract numbers in brackets

Tags: java, regex

Currently, I am struggling with the problem of catching numbers with REGEX 
by using Java

The string which I am trying to catch the numbers in this string value using REGEX 
is this..

```
[TEST][64894]HelloWorld[KGMObilians]
```

My wish is to catch the numbers which are located in [ ].

Would this be possible with Java? 
I could easily take the number by splitting the string, but the company 
wants me to use the regex since it is more safer and faster. please help me.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: The answer is "yes, it can be done". Are you actually wanting the regular expression to doit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String s = "[TEST][64894]HelloWorld[KGMObilians]";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\[\\d+\\]");
Matcher match = patt.matcher(s);
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/YXeHqL)**

And if you dont want the brackets then simply make it like

```
String s = "[TEST][64894]HelloWorld[KGMObilians]";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)\\]");
Matcher match = patt.matcher(s);
while(match.find()){
    System.out.println(match.group(1));
}
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/bSX2oq)**

Answer (score 0):

It takes the number out of the string.

```
    String s = "[TEST][64894]HelloWorld[KGMObilians]";
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\[\\d+\\]");
    Matcher match = patt.matcher(s);
    if (match.find()) {         
        String group = match.group();
        System.out.println(group.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
    }
```